# Delete Duplicate records in CSV file in python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, csv, python-3.x, cmp

#### My INPUT file:

```
1,boss,30
2,go,35
2,nan,45
3,fog,33
4,kd,55
4,gh,56
```

#### Output file should be:

```
1,boss,30
3,fog,33
```

Means my output file should be free from duplicates. I should delete the record which is repeating based on the **column 1**.

#### Code I tried:

```
source_rd = csv.writer(open("Non_duplicate_source.csv", "wb"),delimiter=d)
gok = set()
for rowdups in sort_src:
    if rowdups[0] not in gok:
        source_rd.writerow(rowdups)
        gok.add( rowdups[0])
```

#### Output I got:

```
1,boss,30
2,go,35
3,fog,33
4,kd,55
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For starters, take a look at [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting); I'll edit it for you this time so you can see how it works.

Comment: What is `sort_src`? Also, could you clarify why you didn't expect that output; the duplicates have been removed as required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just loop the file twice.

The first time through, count all the duplicates. Second time through fetch the ones of interest.

```
import csv

gok={}
with open(fn) as fin:
    reader=csv.reader(fin)
    for e in reader:
        gok[e[0]]=gok.setdefault(e[0], 0)+1

with open(fn) as fin:
    reader=csv.reader(fin)
    for e in reader:
        if gok[e[0]]==1:
            print e
```

Prints:

```
['1', 'boss', '30']
['3', 'fog', '33']
```

The reason your method does not work is that once the second instance of the duplicate is seen, the first has already been written.